# Running grid db in multicast mode

Tags: multicast, griddb

I have installled griddb on WSL which by default runs in FIXED mode. The configuration file gs_cluster.json is as below :

```
{
"dataStore":{
    "partitionNum":128,
    "storeBlockSize":"64KB"
},
"cluster": {
    "clusterName": "myCluster",
    "replicationNum": 2,
    "heartbeatInterval": "5s",
    "loadbalanceCheckInterval": "180s",
    "notificationMember":
    [
        {
            "cluster":     {"address": "127.0.0.1", "port": 10010},
            "sync":        {"address": "127.0.0.1", "port": 10020},
            "system":      {"address": "127.0.0.1", "port": 10040},
            "transaction": {"address": "127.0.0.1", "port": 10001},
            "sql":         {"address": "127.0.0.1", "port": 20001}
        }
    ]
},
"sync":{
    "timeoutInterval":"30s"
},
"transaction":{
    "replicationMode":0,
    "replicationTimeoutInterval":"10s"
},
"sql":{
} }
```

This mode runs fine. I am able to connect via jdbc connector as well. Now, I want to run multi-cast mode. On this [official doc](https://docs.griddb.net/architecture/structure-of-griddb/#composition-of-a-cluster), I could find the configuration for FIXED and PROVIDER method but not for multicast method.

I found this [griddb blog](https://griddb.net/en/blog/griddb-using-fixed-list-or-multicast-clustering/) regarding switching from multicast to fixed mode. Referring to this article I made changes to gs_cluster.json as follows:

```
{
"dataStore":{
    "partitionNum":128,
    "storeBlockSize":"64KB"
},
"cluster": {
    "clusterName": "myCluster",
    "replicationNum": 2,
    "notificationInterval":"5s",
    "notificationAddress":"127.0.0.1",
    "notificationPort":20001,
    "heartbeatInterval": "5s",
    "loadbalanceCheckInterval": "180s"
},
"sync":{
    "timeoutInterval":"30s"
},
"transaction":{
    "replicationMode":0,
    "replicationTimeoutInterval":"10s"
},
"sql":{
}}
```

After setting this config, when I run the griddb, it fails to start. I am getting following error:

```
gridstore.service - GridDB database server.
Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/gridstore.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Tue 2024-02-06 20:25:10 IST; 6min ago
Process: 182 ExecStart=/usr/griddb/bin/gridstore start (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

Feb 06 20:25:10 laptop gridstore[337]: A00104: Failed to connect node. (node=127.0.0.1:10040)
Feb 06 20:25:10 laptop gridstore[337]: Confirm node is started.
Feb 06 20:25:10 laptop gridstore[337]: URLError <urlopen error [Errno 111] Connection refused>
Feb 06 20:25:10 laptop gridstore[182]: F01006: Leavecluster error
Feb 06 20:25:10 laptop gridstore[182]: Stopped.
Feb 06 20:25:10 laptop gridstore[182]: F01002: Startnode error
Feb 06 20:25:10 laptop gridstore[182]: [ FAILED ]
Feb 06 20:25:10 laptop systemd[1]: gridstore.service: Control process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
Feb 06 20:25:10 laptop systemd[1]: gridstore.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
Feb 06 20:25:10 laptop systemd[1]: Failed to start GridDB database server..
```

Kindly let me know what I am missing in the configuration.